# Can't revoke permissions on Redshift

Tags: permissions, redshift

I'm having a issue revoking privileges that is stopping me from droping users

```
select usename, acl.*
from pg_default_acl as acl join pg_user on usesysid = defacluser
where usename = 'user1';
```

gives me:

```
|usename|defacluser|defaclnamespace|defaclobjtype|defaclacl             |
|-------|----------|---------------|-------------|----------------------|
|user1 |143       |0              |r            |{user1=awdRxt/user1}|
```

With a view provided by amazon (`v_get_obj_priv_by_user`) I execute this to get the schemas/databases with permissions to this user:

```
select 'alter table '+schemaname+'.'+tablename+' owner to y;' from pg_tables where tableowner like 'user1';

select distinct 'revoke all on schema '+schemaname+' from user1;' from admin.v_get_obj_priv_by_user where usename like 'user1';

select distinct 'revoke all on all tables in schema '+schemaname+' from user1;' from admin.v_get_obj_priv_by_user where usename like 'user1'
```

Got this 2 responses from previous queries

```
revoke all on schema xxx from user1;

revoke all on all tables in schema xxx from user1;
```

I ran them, have no errors, but the permissions are still there and the queries using `v_get_obj_priv_by_user` keep returning the same results.

Obviously when later I try to drop the user have this error:

> SQL Error [2BP01]: ERROR: user "user1" cannot be dropped because some
> objects depend on it   Detail: owner of default privileges on new
> relations belonging to user user1

Any idea of what could I been doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
alter default privileges for user <user> revoke all on tables from <user>;
alter default privileges for user <user> grant all on tables to <user>;
drop user <user>;
```